# Exploding Column in Databricks row-wise

Tags: sql, databricks

I have an `array type` column `subscription` in my table with columns
**Sample Table**

```
+-------+--------+----+----------+
|user_id| Subscription|Activity  |
+-------+-------------+----------+
|111    |[A,C,B]      |20        |
|-------+-------------+----------+
|222    |[C,A]        |10        |
|-------+-------------+----------+
|333    |[B]          | 5        |
+-------+-------------+----------+
```

I want to change my table to this.
**Output Required**

```
+-------+--------+----+----------+
|user_id| Subscription|Activity  |
+-------+-------------+----------+
|111    |A            |20        |
|-------+-------------+----------+
|111    |C            |20        |
|-------+-------------+----------+
|111    |B            |20        |
+-------+-------------+----------+
|222    |C            |10        |
|-------+-------------+----------+
|222    |A            |10        |
|-------+-------------+----------+
|333    |B            | 5        |
+-------+-------------+----------+
```

I know this can be achieved using Explode, but not sure about it.
I am running my query in Databricks. SQL

Comment: To clarify, are you not sure about how to use Explode, or rather, you are trying to find another method of doing this?

Comment: I tried to ```unnest(subscription)``` but it is not working in Databricks SQL. I want to know by any means how can I get desired result @Isolated

Answer (score 1):

I would use `explode` to achieve your desired output.

```
with my_data as (
  select 111 as user_id, array('A', 'C', 'B') as subscription, 20 as activity union all 
  select 222, array('C','A'), 10 union all 
  select 333, array('B'), 5
)
select user_id, explode(subscription) as subscription, activity
from my_data
```

Output

| user_id | subscription | activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | A | 20 |
| 111 | C | 20 |
| 111 | B | 20 |
| 222 | C | 10 |
| 222 | A | 10 |
| 333 | B | 5 |

Answer (score 0):

This will give us the desired output
`SELECT *, explode(subscription) as subscription from my_tb`